# Modelling factors as probabilities

Tags: probability

A, B, and C are statements.

$P(A, B)$ represents probability that statements $A$ and $B$ are both true.

$P(A, B) + P(A, C) = P(A, B, C)$

Does this means $B$ and $C$ are independent?

Comment: This equation is very hard to satisfy.  $P(A,B)≥P(A,B,C)$ in general, so $P(A,C)=0$ in your situation.  Similarly $P(A,B)=0$ and $P(A,B,C)=0$.

Comment: To your specific question, no.  Let $A$ be any event with probability $0$.  Then all three of your terms are $0$ so your equation holds, even if $B=C$.  For that matter, let $B=C$ and let $A$ be the complementary event.  Then, again, all three of your terms are $0$.

Comment: @lulu: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @lulu but statements are true or are not true, right? So don't we have $P(B),P(C)\in\{0,1\}$ here?

Comment: @drhab  Not sure what you are saying.  As far as I can see there are no restrictions on $P(B),P(C)$ other than that they are probabilities (hence in the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @lulu The word "statement" appears a bit strange to me in this context and I tend to read it as or link it with "sentence" in logic which is boolean-valued. If we want to speak of the probability that a sentence is true then we can only use degenerated probabilities. Never mind, though.

Comment: @drhab  Ah, I see.  I ignored the use of "statement"...I just took $A,B,C$ for events and $P(A)$, or whatever, for "the probability that $A$ occurs".  I don't think it really changes anything, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation is severely restrictive.  It is clear, for example, that for any three events $A,B,C$ we must have $$P(A,B)≥P(A,B,C)\quad \&\quad P(A,C)≥P(A,B,C)$$

If we require that your equation hold, this immediately tells us that $$P(A,B)=0\quad P(A,C)=0\quad P(A,B,C)=0$$

Of course, whenever all three of those probabilities vanish, your equation holds.

There is no need for $B,C$ to be independent.  Indeed let $B=C$ and let $A$ be the complementary event (So event $A$ excludes both $B$ and $C$).  Then all three probabilities vanish so your equation holds.